# Finding Fisher Matrix for Line Fitting

Tags: experiment-design, fisher-information

I am going through the "Fitting a Line" example from [here](http://wittman.physics.ucdavis.edu/Fisher-matrix-guide.pdf).

$f_1 = ax_1 + b$ and $f_2 = ax_2 + b$ are the models used to observed two data points in $R^2$. If $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ is the uncertainity in measuring $x_1$ and $x_2$, how do you calculate the Fisher information matrix?

I can't get to the solution they got to on Page 4.

Comment: There isn't enough information provided in your post to answer the question: your models *must* specify the possible distributions of all random quantities.

Comment: I agree. I am just trying to assume a Gaussian model with variance $\sigma_i$ while measuring $x_i$ and see if I reach the solution proposed in the paper. If that were true, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

I got it. What I got wrong in my understanding was that we are trying to estimate $a$ and $b$, not the $ x_i$s.

In that case,

\begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{a}} = x_i, \frac{\partial{f_i}}{\partial{b}} = 1.
\end{equation}

Extending this to find the Fisher Information Matrix gives,

\begin{equation}
F =
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \frac{x_1^2}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{x_2^2}{\sigma_2^2} & \frac{x_1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{x_2}{\sigma_2^2} \\
    \frac{x_1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{x_2}{\sigma_2^2} & \frac{1}{\sigma_1^2} + \frac{1}{\sigma_2^2}
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}